# What can cause octal/hex "numbers" in html be displayed with the times symbol on the place of x? How to fix it?

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

Context: I'm adjusting styles for a blockchain explorer, so it has many hex numbers as text (like `0xa4a282`). The problem is, they are not all represented the same: some of them are shown normally, with `x` symbol, while others are shown with something like `&times;` symbol:

[image]

The unexpected thing is – inspector shows that all of them are in fact written with `x` (I can also confirm this with copy-pasting the rendered text into a text editor).
Narrowing down the problem, I've figured out that the behavior depends on the symbol going after `x`: if it's a letter, it is represented as "x", but if it's a number, it becomes "×" (visually). Well, in fact this is more complicated: if I remove all the html from body and set it to just

```
<body>
    <div>0xa 0xA 0x3 0x9 0x x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x0 xa xA</div>
    <div>0x3 0x9 0x x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x0 xa xA</div>
    <div>x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x0 xa xA</div>
</body>
```

this is the result (note different results for x1, presumably depending on what is the previous symbol):

[image: ouch, this is complicated]

The source of the problem is the Inter font: removing it from css applied to the elements removes the effect. Here's an MCVE:

```css
body {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet" data-optimized-fonts="true">

<div>0xa 0xA 0x3 0x9 0x x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x0 xa xA</div>
<div>0x3 0x9 0x x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x0 xa xA</div>
<div>x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 x0 xa xA</div>
```

What is this effect (are these ligatures? monograms? something else)? How to get rid of it (can I do this while keeping the font family)? I'm not seeing the effect when testing the font [on Google Fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter#type-tester).

Comment: That font clearly has programming ligatures for all combinations of digit + x + digit.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález thanks, looks like `font-variant-ligatures: none;` is an option to fix this. Not sure why I don't see this in Google Fonts though. Found more details here: https://rsms.me/inter/#features/calt

Comment: I do see them in Google Fonts preview: https://i.imgur.com/Y3Z18mX.png

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, yeah, the preview works as expected, while Type Tester seems to have some glitches. When I load the page and start typing 0x1, it is not dispayed as a ligature, not sure why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, those are ligatures of the Inter font ([more on that](https://rsms.me/inter/#features/calt)). I'm not sure why this is not always reproduced by the [Googel Fonts' Type Tester](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Inter#type-tester) (when I load the page and start typing 0x1, it is not dispayed as a ligature), but the "preview" input reproduces this.

I'm not aware if a specific ligature can be switched off, but for me setting

```
body {
    font-variant-ligatures: none;
}
```

was good enough.